# INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION error when installing Yahoo Mail apk on Samsung Galaxy S6 using Appium

Tags: android, email, appium

For automation testing purposes I cannot install the app using the Google Play store.  I need to install it manually using the Appium.

I can install yahoo mail on a Samsung S7 and an LG G5 but I get INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION error when installing Yahoo Mail on a Samsung Galaxy S6.

Here is the full error message.
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.permissions.YAHOO_INTER_APP pkg=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail.att]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Android 5.0+, two apps cannot have the same `<permission>` element, creating the same permission, unless they are signed by the same signing key. In your case, the Galaxy S6 already has something that defined this permission, and it has a different signing key than the one that somebody used to sign your APK.

Comment: Thank you for your information.  I just want to add that the phone has been factory reset and the issue still happens.

Comment: @user6405863: That just means that this Yahoo code shipped with the device. Samsung strikes licensing deals with a variety of firms for pre-loaded software. In this case, they apparently struck a deal with Yahoo.

Comment: I think you are right about Samsung having some code only in the S6.  If I find a fix I will update here.  

Btw, your book was the first one I read when I started learning to code in Android.  Thank you.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it possible to change the `signing key` of an app after putting it on play store ? Thanks.

Comment: @ankalagba: Not usually, and definitely not for older devices. Newer versions of Android do offer some support for this sort of thing, but I have no idea if Google Play offers any straightforward way to request that sort of change.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just started with play store, I have recently put two apps on play store wich have the same <permission> element. When I install first the `app A` from play store, I will not be able to install the `app B`. When I first install the `app B` from play store, I will not be able to install the `app A`. One of my apps is not able to install when I install the other app first. Any idea about how to solve that issue ? Thanks again.

Comment: @ankalagba: I am assuming that they were signed with separate signing keys. If so, you could ship an update to one of the apps that switches to some new custom permission, one with a different name, so it does not collide with the permission from the other app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had the same issue as in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57133565/12943545 And I solved it with your anwser here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57133590/12943545 At here: `App B has identical <permission> elements as App A and both App A and App B are signed by the same signing key`. But because I'm beginner in android, I forgot to sign my two apps with the same signing key, and now It is too late for me I have already put them on play store. I don't know how to do to not make my two apps collide. Thanks again.

Comment: @CommonsWare According to your answer wich solved my last issue: `App B has identical <permission> elements as App A and both App A and App B are signed by the same signing key`, I can not do your suggestion: `you could ship an update to one of the apps that switches to some new custom permission, one with a different name.` Do you see ? Please help me, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @ankalagba: "I can not do your suggestion" -- then you would need to remove one of the two apps from the Play Store and submit a replacement, with a new application ID, that is signed by the same signing key as the other shipping app.

Comment: @CommonsWare `you would need to remove one of the two apps from the Play Store and submit a replacement, with a new application ID, that is signed by the same signing key as the other shipping app`. -- Is that the only solution for that issue ? Removing one app to replace it by another one with a new application ID is the last thing I want to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have other solutions for you. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, with all of the relevant details, and see if somebody else has suggestions. Be sure to explain what you are using this custom permission for, as the suggestions might involve alternative solutions that avoid the need for having the custom permission in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hello, I have opened an issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67547283/12943545